# trying to get the messages frame work to display message if valid and invalid

Tags: django, django-forms

For some reason django displays both success message and failure message when I'm trying to display messages on form creation and update. Here I'm copy pasting the code for only the form creation.

The view I'm using is:

```
#function based views
def post_create(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
    # if request.method == "POST":
    #     # print(request.POST)
    #     print("title: ", request.POST.get("title"))
    #     print("content: ",request.POST.get("content"))
    if form.is_valid():
        instance=form.save(commit=False)
        print(form.cleaned_data.get("title"))
        instance.save()
        #a success message
        messages.success(request, "Successfully Created")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Post Not Created")

    context= {
        "form":form
    }
    return render(request, "post_form.html",context)
```

and the `Post` model is also very basic:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)#;
    content = models.TextField()#:
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, auto_now_add=False)#; save and update everytime change is done
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add = True)#; auto_now_add = save and set one time


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    #python3
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={"id":self.id})
```

the form template is:

```
<html>
    <head><title>new page</title></head>
    <body>
        <h1>Form</h1>

        <form method="POST" action="">

            {{ form.as_p }}{% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" value="Create Post"/>

        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

and the page where the message gets displayed is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            index.html
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>

        {% if messages %}

            <ul class="messages">
                {% for message in messages %}
                <li {% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}

            <h1><b>TITLE: </b>{{ title }}</h1>
        <hr/>
            {{ instance.title }} <br/>
            {{ instance.content }}<br/>
            {{ instance.updated }}<br/>
            {{ instance.timestamp }}<br/>


        Template is working!!
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I don't know why but for some reason, I create the form and the data is valid:
[image]

The form gets created all right , and the page gets redirected all right, but the messages displayed are quite wrong. I mean, why is both the success and failure message being displayed simultaneously:

---

[image]

what is the problem here and how do I solve this?

Comment: You did not check if `request.method == 'POST'`, therefore `form.is_valid()` is called in both GET and POST, your form is not valid if it is a GET (that is when you first load the form)

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
def post_create(request):

    form = PostForm()
    if request.method =='POST':

        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        # if request.method == "POST":
        #     # print(request.POST)
        #     print("title: ", request.POST.get("title"))
        #     print("content: ",request.POST.get("content"))
        if form.is_valid():
            instance=form.save(commit=False)
            print(form.cleaned_data.get("title"))
            instance.save()
            #a success message
            messages.success(request, "Successfully Created")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
        else:

             messages.error(request, "Post Not Created")
             context= {
                        "form":form
                    }
            return render(request, "post_form.html",context) 

    else:
        context= {"form":form }
        return render(request, "post_form.html",context)
```